# UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.1 data type of expression is not boolean

Tags: java, regex, ucanaccess

I have a table like the following image

[image]

I need to get all the English words that its Kurdish Word contains "بةرز",
So i cant use

```
select English from Table1 where Kurdish like '%بةرز%';
```

because it also accepts the words that are sub-string in another word like these ،يبلبةرز ، سيس بةرز
,
And when i try to use Regular Expression in my query:

```
query = "SELECT English FROM Table1 WHERE Kurdish REGEXP '^[.، ]*("+"بةرز" +")[ ،.]*$'";
s.execute(query);
```

it shows the following Exception

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.1 data type of expression is not boolean
```

Is the problem is with my regular expression or what?
Note that i'am using UCanAccess for my database connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```java
columnName REGEXP 'pattern'
```

I believe you need to use

```java
REGEXP_MATCHES(columnName, 'pattern')
```

This seems to work for me ...

```java
String targetString = "بةرز";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT English FROM Table1 " +
        "WHERE Kurdish = ? " +
            "OR REGEXP_MATCHES(Kurdish, ?) " +
            "OR REGEXP_MATCHES(Kurdish, ?) " +
            "OR REGEXP_MATCHES(Kurdish, ?) ")) {
    ps.setString(1, targetString);
    ps.setString(2, "^" + targetString + "[.، ]+.*");
    ps.setString(3, ".*[.، ]+" + targetString + "$");
    ps.setString(4, ".*[.، ]+" + targetString + "[.، ]+.*");
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

... although there might be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Another solution may be using the like clause with regex based criteria(but I can't say if it's more or less elegant, it's simply access compliant and supported by both access and ucanaccess). See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583752/regular-expression-matching-when-querying-an-access-database-with-ucanaccess

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its worked fine with some edit
`ps.setString(1, targetString );
ps.setString(2, "^[. ]*" + targetString + "[ ]*[:،,]+[ .]*$");
ps.setString(3, "^[. ]*[:،,]+[ ]*" + targetString + "[. ]*$");
ps.setString(4, "^[. ]*[:،,]+[ ]*" + targetString + "[ ]*[:،,]+[ .]*$");`